# Find solution for 20x20 table with 20 unique values that must not repeat on row or column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to finish the table below with the 20 values (letters A to T) distributed so that there are no repetitions of a value on the same row or the same column.

Any ideas how to approach this? I started manually, got to J and the problems began :)

| Level | Option 1 | Option 2 | Option 3 | Option 4 | Option 5 | Option 6 | Option 7 | Option 8 | Option 9 | Option 10 | Option 11 | Option 12 | Option 13 | Option 14 | Option 15 | Option 16 | Option 17 | Option 18 | Option 19 | Option 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T |
| 2 | B |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | C |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | D |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | E |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | F |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | G |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | H |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | I |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | J |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | K |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | L |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | M |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | N |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | O |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | P |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17 | Q |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 18 | R |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 19 | S |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I can provide context on why I need this table, but I didn't think it would add any value to the question. I've researched distribution of values in excel and couldn't find anything, sadly.

As for b), I attempted manually distributing values, while putting in place formulas to check if I'm breaking the rules but am stuck after a while.

I haven't tried any automated solutions since I can't think of any.

Comment: tbh, as a 'puzzle' it solves itself. You already got enough to know how to fill the rest. How to make it calculate… I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the answer from @Tetsujin. On B2, enter the following formula:

```
=CHAR(65+IF(COLUMN(INDIRECT(A2&"1"))<20,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A2&"1")),COLUMN(INDIRECT(A2&"1"))-20))
```

Drag it down, then right to fill the other cells.

If you have Excel 365, you can also use:

```
=LET(x,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A2&"1")),CHAR(65+IF(x<20,x,x-20)))
```

This will be the result.

[image: Result]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

| Level | Option 1 | Option 2 | Option 3 | Option 4 | Option 5 | ... | Option 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | E | ... | T |
| 2 | B | C | D | E | F | ... | A |
| 3 | C | D | E | F | G | ... | B |
| 4 | D | E |  |  |  | ... | C |
| 5 | E | F |  |  |  |  | D |
| 6 | F | G |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | G |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | H |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | I |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | J |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | K |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | L |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | M |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | N |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | O |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | P |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17 | Q |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 18 | R |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 19 | S |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |